# can't load parquet timestamp using Synapse serverless pool's OPENROWSET

Tags: sql-server, timestamp, parquet, azure-synapse

### TL;DR

The first possible parquet timestamp, `0001-01-01 00:00:00.000` cannot be loaded with Azure Synapse Serverless SQL Pools, as `DATETIME2` or any other type. I'm baffled bc the [`DATETIME2` docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime2-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#datetime2-description) say that this is within the acceptable range:

> | Property | Value |
> | --- | --- |
> | Date range | 0001-01-01 through 9999-12-31 January 1,1 CE through December 31, 9999 CE |
> | Time range | 00:00:00 through 23:59:59.9999999 |

user @RandolphWest found [this relevant thread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/181820/reading-datetime-from-parquet.html) that gets the same error message but they lay the blame on ADF.

### Reproducible Example

Here's how to make a file that will reproduce the error. Alternatively, here's a [Dropbox link to the file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gfm37p72k6pcg7t/part-00000-dc75e161-7779-467e-a14d-54b531d7f340-c000.snappy.parquet?dl=0)

#### Make a parquet file

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import to_timestamp
dfx = (
    spark.createDataFrame(
        data = [ ("1","0001-01-01 00:00:00.000")],
        schema=["id","my_ts"])
    .withColumn("my_ts",to_timestamp("my_ts"))
)
dfx.write.parquet('abfss://<MY-CONTAINER>@<MY-WORKSPACE>.dfs.core.windows.net/dfx')
display(dfx)
```

```
+---+-------------------+
| id|              my_ts|
+---+-------------------+
|  1|0001-01-01 00:00:00|
+---+-------------------+
```

#### Load a parquet file

```sql
SELECT
    TOP 100 *
FROM
    OPENROWSET(
        BULK 'https://<MY-WORKSPACE>.dfs.core.windows.net/<MY-CONTAINER>/dfx/**',
        FORMAT = 'PARQUET'
    ) AS [result]
```

Error message

```
Failed to execute query.
Error: Error handling external file: 'Inserting value to batch for column type DATETIME2 failed.
Invalid argument provided.'.
File/External table name: 'https://<MY-WORKSPACE>.dfs.core.windows.net/<MY-CONTAINER>/dfx/part-00015-f98c11bd-ffb4-45de-b505-0aa226183098-c000.snappy.parquet'.
Statement ID: {F3062AA6-DD96-4271-A093-6D24F8E0C2FE} | Query hash: 0x9CCB08D8E9D29322 | Distributed request ID: {D0BA926E-FAB2-47DD-8309-BE91DFAC48F8}.
Total size of data scanned is 1 megabytes, total size of data moved is 0 megabytes, total size of data written is 0 megabytes.
```

Comment: Did you try with a T in the middle? _a la_ `0001-01-01T00:00:00.000`

Comment: @RandolphWest I like your thinking!  however the string format isn't important. the string gets successfully converted to a timestamp without issue. it's only after the timestamp-formatted column (saved to parquet) is loaded into Synapse SQL that the issue occurs.

Comment: Is this related to your issue? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/181820/reading-datetime-from-parquet.html. Looks like there's a "no year zero" issue at play.

Comment: I believe this to be a bug in Synapse. the error message does look to be the same, though they're blaming ADF for the conversion. in this case, I'm using pyspark and parquet out of the box. but great find! def related.

Comment: Ew, this looks like an Excel thing (doesn't it always subtract 2 days when converting a numeric to a date?)

Comment: I am also facing this issue.

Comment: Anyone found as solution?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error, I've solved this issue saving as datatype **string** (so do not use to_timestamp) in the adls and then converting to **datetime2** into the Synapse query. This sound strange but it actually works.
using your code it will be something like this:

```
SELECT
    cast(my_ts as datetime2) as my_ts
FROM
    OPENROWSET(
        BULK 'https://<MY-WORKSPACE>.dfs.core.windows.net/<MY-CONTAINER>/dfx/**',
        FORMAT = 'PARQUET'
    ) WITH (my_ts as nvarchar(27)) AS [result]
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that it is a bug with Synapse serverless pool's parquet reader. I'm not sure if it has been fixed yet.